PowerShell: How to do Autocompletion for proxy functions?
I have a function like:
function helf {
    Get-Help -Full @args
}

This results in autocompletion for helf -<tab> no longer working:
> TabExpansion2 "helf -" | select -Expand CompletionMatches
[ NO RESULT ]

I've noticed however that oss, which is actually not an alias of Out-String, but a proxy function of Out-String -Stream, does have working autocomplete:
> gcm oss

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        oss


> TabExpansion2 "Out-String -Stream -" | select -Expand CompletionMatches

CompletionText       ListItemText           ResultType ToolTip
--------------       ------------           ---------- -------
-Width               Width               ParameterName [int] Width
-InputObject         InputObject         ParameterName [psobject] InputObject
-Verbose             Verbose             ParameterName [switch] Verbose
-Debug               Debug               ParameterName [switch] Debug
-ErrorAction         ErrorAction         ParameterName [ActionPreference] ErrorAction
-WarningAction       WarningAction       ParameterName [ActionPreference] WarningAction
-InformationAction   InformationAction   ParameterName [ActionPreference] InformationAction
-ProgressAction      ProgressAction      ParameterName [ActionPreference] ProgressAction
-ErrorVariable       ErrorVariable       ParameterName [string] ErrorVariable
-WarningVariable     WarningVariable     ParameterName [string] WarningVariable
-InformationVariable InformationVariable ParameterName [string] InformationVariable
-OutVariable         OutVariable         ParameterName [string] OutVariable
-OutBuffer           OutBuffer           ParameterName [int] OutBuffer
-PipelineVariable    PipelineVariable    ParameterName [string] PipelineVariable


> TabExpansion2 "oss -" | select -Expand CompletionMatches

CompletionText       ListItemText           ResultType ToolTip
--------------       ------------           ---------- -------
-Width               Width               ParameterName [int] Width
-InputObject         InputObject         ParameterName [psobject] InputObject
-Verbose             Verbose             ParameterName [switch] Verbose
-Debug               Debug               ParameterName [switch] Debug
-ErrorAction         ErrorAction         ParameterName [ActionPreference] ErrorAction
-WarningAction       WarningAction       ParameterName [ActionPreference] WarningAction
-InformationAction   InformationAction   ParameterName [ActionPreference] InformationAction
-ProgressAction      ProgressAction      ParameterName [ActionPreference] ProgressAction
-ErrorVariable       ErrorVariable       ParameterName [string] ErrorVariable
-WarningVariable     WarningVariable     ParameterName [string] WarningVariable
-InformationVariable InformationVariable ParameterName [string] InformationVariable
-OutVariable         OutVariable         ParameterName [string] OutVariable
-OutBuffer           OutBuffer           ParameterName [int] OutBuffer
-PipelineVariable    PipelineVariable    ParameterName [string] PipelineVariable


The question is: How would I accomplish this for my own proxy functions?

Tab completion isn't working because your hef function doesn't have any parameters. If you want to create a real proxy function you need to use ProxyCommand.Create or add to hef those parameters you consider needed.
So, to get the fully auto-generated proxy function body:
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create((Get-Command Get-Help))

Or, to get the command's param block and pick from there which parameters you deem needed:
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetParamBlock((Get-Command Get-Help))

Relevant Documentations:

about_functions
about_parameters


If you want your hef function to default to -Full but also have the same parameters as Get-Help and be reduced to its minimal expression (no pipeline capabilities, etc) this is how it should look:
function hef {
    [CmdletBinding(
        DefaultParameterSetName = 'AllUsersView',
        HelpUri = 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2096483')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [string]
        ${Name},

        [string]
        ${Path},

        [ValidateSet(
            'Alias', 'Cmdlet', 'Provider', 'General', 'FAQ',
            'Glossary', 'HelpFile', 'ScriptCommand', 'Function',
            'Filter', 'ExternalScript', 'All', 'DefaultHelp',
            'Workflow', 'DscResource', 'Class', 'Configuration')]
        [string[]]
        ${Category},

        [string[]]
        ${Component},

        [string[]]
        ${Functionality},

        [string[]]
        ${Role}
    )

    Get-Help @PSBoundParameters -Full
}


I see, thanks. Is there an elegant way to create the function with the returned text with e.g. -Full without including the complete function block. A single proxy command would almost double my PowerShell profile by itself otherwise.

@DmitrijDrandarov does that update help?

I wish there was a simpler/more concise way to achieve this, but I believe you that this is all there is currently in PowerShell, so I'll mark your answer as the solution. Thanks

@DmitrijDrandarov can you define more concise? you could remove peaces from the param block like all the types ([string], [string[]]..) to reduce space but this is something that not only helps with the function metadata but also prevents passing an argument that is not of the correct type and also helps with type coercion when possible

My wishful idea would be to have something that could be used as follows: New-ProxyFunction -Name helf -Command Get-Help -DefaultParameters '-Full' (similar to New-Alias syntax), which would create the appropriate proxy function with $PSBoundParameters['Full'] = $true in its begin block or even a String concatination. The only idea I'd have, would be to use String manipulation to do this with the resulting String from [Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create(...).

@DmitrijDrandarov i see, yeah thats not something that exists built-in but is something that could be accomplished by writing the logic in a function. Sounds like a good project for a module
